# Import specific data from a txt in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a file (Map_1.hdr) generate from an instrument, here the file:

```
    ENVI
    description = {ROI id #1}
    samples = 16
    lines   = 4
    bands   = 1025
    data type = 4
    interleave = bip
    wavelength = 
    pixel size = {9.38E-07, 7.5E-07}
    x-start and y-start = {0.027363358, -0.007902135}
```

And I need to get specific data from the last 2 rows, these data:

```
pixel_size = c(9.38E-07,7.5E-07)
origin = (0.027363358, -0.007902135)
```

Here my (incomplete) attempt:

```
library(R.utils)
rem <- 2
nL <- countLines("Map_1.hdr")
df <- read.csv("Map_1.hdr", header=FALSE, sep=" ", skip=nL-rem, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With this, I got the last two rows but I am still far away to clean the rest. Is there any other way to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used instead:

```
 txt <-"   ENVI
    description = {ROI id #1}
    samples = 16
    lines   = 4
    bands   = 1025
    data type = 4
    interleave = bip
    wavelength = 
    pixel size = {9.38E-07, 7.5E-07}
    x-start and y-start = {0.027363358, -0.007902135}"
rem <- 2
nL <- length(readLines(textConnection(txt)))
df <- read.delim(text=gsub(patt = "^.+\\{|\\}", 
                                 # ^^^^^^     removes everything upto last '{' 
                                    #     ^^^ as well as the trailing '}' 
                                    #    ^    the `|` char is regex logical OR
                           repl = "",  # by replacing with length zero character
                             readLines(textConnection(txt))), # input text or file
                    header=FALSE, sep=",",  # left the comma in so it can be 'sep'
                    skip=nL-rem, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
           V1           V2
1 0.000000938  0.000000750
2 0.027363358 -0.007902135
```

You can replace the instances of `readLines(textConnection(txt))` with your file name and drop the text= argument. (It's useful of constructing working, testable examples.)

Comment: Great! It works if I copy and paste your attempt. Unfortunately I cannot understand (completely ) how should I modify to get a general code... `txt <-read.csv("Map_1.hdr")
rem <- 2
nL <- length(readLines(textConnection(txt)))
df <- read.delim(text=gsub("^.+\\{|\\}","", readLines(textConnection(txt))), header=FALSE, sep=",", skip=nL-rem, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: I'll put some explanatory comments "inline"

Comment: If it works you can checkmark it even if you can't upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Could this work? Not sure if I entirely understand what output you want:

```
>attempt <- read.table("~/"Map_1.hdr"",  sep= "=", stringsAsFactors = F)

> tail(attempt,2)$ENVI
[1] " {9.38E-07, 7.5E-07}"         " {0.027363358, -0.007902135}"
> tail(attempt,2)$ENVI[1]
[1] " {9.38E-07, 7.5E-07}"
> tail(attempt,2)$ENVI[2]
[1] " {0.027363358, -0.007902135}"
```

You can then use `strsplit` and `gsub` to get what you need from there?

```
> strsplit(gsub('[\\{}]', "", tail(attempt,2)$ENVI[1]),",")[[1]][1]
[1] " 9.38E-07"
> strsplit(gsub('[\\{}]', "", tail(attempt,2)$ENVI[1]),",")[[1]][2]
[1] " 7.5E-07"
```